# Phonegap - ajax connection to the server was unsuccessful

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm stuck everything works fine it calls the data via ajax jsonp crossdomain, but just after a few seconds my app throws the "connection to the server was unsuccessful" error then my app closes.

I've tried all sorts of solutions.

- I've added super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 7000); to my manifest java file.
- I've added a main.html file to redirect to index.html as it seems like a timeout issue.

Here is a look at my ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({

                      url: 'http://www.carmag.co.za/api/?q=news&callback=?', // The callback=? part is very importatnt to use in you get URL
                      crossDomain:true,
                      type: 'GET',
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      jsonp: 'jsonp',
                      complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                        //called when complete
                      },
                      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                            //alert(item.title);




                            var thumbnail = '<img src="'+ item.thumnail +'" class="single-thumb">';
                            var news =  '<div class="row news readmore-'+ item.id +'" ><div class="small-12 background-body f1-news"><img src="'+ item.thumnail +'" class="img-news"><h4>'+ item.title + 
                            '</h4> <div class="excerpt">'+ item.excerpt +' <p class="news-date">'+ item.date +'</p> <a href="#" class="readmore theid-'+ item.id +'" data-content="<h2>'+ item.title +'</h2>' + escapeHtml(item.content)  +'">Read More</a></div></div></div>';

                        $('#latestnews').append(news);
                        });
                        /*$('.subcontent').html('news loaded');*/
                      },
                      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                      }
            });
```

I'm running out of ideas.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try increasing ajax timeout value...

Comment: I've increased the timeout for ajax but still the same issue.

Comment: For jquery and Jqm r using CDN ? and trying increasing loadtimeoutvalue from 7000 to 60000

Comment: No not using CDN it's a local copy compiled in to the APK. I've already set it to 70000 not working at all.

Comment: Do you wait the deviceready event before you do your ajax call? (seems to me that you have this error because you are doing the ajax call directly at the page load)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and report back.

Comment: I've added the device ready around my ajax code, it still does the same thing. Just a bit faster now.